# When $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals

Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and let $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ be the ideal generated by $u,v,w$.

It is known that for two elements the following result holds:
$\langle u,v \rangle$ is a maximal ideal if and only if the curves $u=0$ and $v=0$ intersect at a single point and transversely;
see, for example, the first comment to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366015/in-mathbbcx-y-if-langle-u-v-rangle-is-a-maximal-ideal-then-langle) question.

I am looking for a similar result for three elements and wonder if the following claim is true:

> **Claim:**
> Assume that no pair of elements of $\{u,v,w\}$ generates a maximal ideal.
> Then,
> $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ is a maximal ideal if and only if the curves $u=0$, $v=0$ and $w=0$ intersect at a single point and at that single point every pair of curves intersect transversely.

Remark: The assumption excludes cases like $u=y,v=x^2+x,w=x$ which generate a maximal ideal,
but $v=0$ and $w=0$ intersect at $(0,0)$ not transversely.

I have asked the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4878133/in-mathbbcx-y-when-langle-u-v-rangle-is-maximal-and-when-langle-u), but got no comments.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, the one who downvoted, please let me know what is wrong with my question and if it is trivially true or trivially false. Thank you.

Comment: $\langle y-x^2,y+x^2,x \rangle$ contradicts my claim..

Comment: Perhaps we should require that at least two pairs of curves out of the three pairs intersect at that single point transversally?

Comment: Actually, $\langle y-x^2,y+x^2,x \rangle$ does not contradict my claim, since $\langle y-x^2,x \rangle$ is already a maximal ideal.

Comment: An example where my claim holds: $u=y+x$, $v=y+x^2$, $w=x+x^2$. Every pair from $\{u,v,w \}$ do not generate a maximal ideal, since every pair has more than one common zero: $\{u,v\}$ have two common zeros $(0,0)$ and $(1,-1)$; $\{v,w\}$ have two common zeros $(0,0)$ and $(-1,-1)$ and $\{u,w\}$ have infinitely many zeros of the form $\{(a,a^2)\}_{a \in \mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Next, we see that $(0,0)$ is a single common zero for the three and at $(0,0)$ every pair of curves $\{y+x=0, y+x^2=0, x+x^2=0\}=\{y=-x,y=-x^2,x(x+1)=0\}$ intersect transversally. What am I missing?

Comment: I think the correct statement should be that the zero locus is a single point and that at least one pair of the curves intersects transversely there.  This should mean that the scheme theoretic intersection of the curves is just the point.

Comment: @JackHuizenga, thank you very much for your comment! Please, could you post your comment (with slightly more details) as an answer? I 'guessed' (according to my examples, without the condition on the pairs not generating a maximal ideals) that at least two pairs of the curves intersects transversely at that single zero point, but your weaker condition is probably the correct one.

Comment: @JackHuizenga, please: (1) Your statement does not require that no pair generates a maximal ideal (it includes such cases); if we remove that condition in my claim we get cases where $\langle u,v,w \rangle$ is maximal but only one or two pairs intersect transversely at  the single zero point--it would be nice to see an example for this, maybe I will think about it. (2) Just to make sure: Your statement actually applies for any finite number $f_1,\ldots,f_n \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$, namely: $\langle f_1,\ldots,f_n \rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ if and only if "your statement".

Comment: More precisely: "if we remove that condition in my claim we get cases where ⟨u,v,w⟩
is maximal but only one or two pairs intersect transversely at the single zero point--it would be nice to see an example for exactly one pair that intersects transversely, since we have already seen examples where exactly two pairs (or exactly three pairs) intersect transversely."

Comment: $\langle y,x^2,x \rangle$ is not an example for having exactly one pair that intersects transversely, since there are two such pairs. Notice that if we consider $\langle y,x^2 \rangle$, then $(0,0)$ has multiplicity two, so $(0,0)$ is not a single zero point, and indeed that two-generated ideal is not maximal.

Comment: Of course, when we say "a single zero point" we count multiplicity; for example, the three generators of $\langle x^2,y^2,x^2y^2 \rangle$ has two common zeros, namely, $(0,0)$ with multiplicity two.